# I can't write a complex equation in code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, math, equation

I have been trying to turn this one conplex equation into code and it appears that I might have done something wrong. Here's the image of the equation:

[image: Here]

Here's is the first code I tried using to convert the equation into code.

```
double answer = 1 - (Math.Pow(f, n) * ((s * l / f) + Math.Pow((20 / f), w) / Math.Pow(20, n)));
```

Here is the code that I used in my second attempt:

```
double answer = 1 - Math.Pow(f, n) * ((s * l) / f) + Math.Pow((20 / f), w) / Math.Pow(20, n);
```

If I assume that every variable of the equation is 2, than I get -.02. But when I ran the code, the first attempt code returned a value of -8, while the second attempt returned -6.75.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong in my code right now? And also sorry if I'm bad at explaining stuffs.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] that we could copy and paste into a console app. Be sure to include sample inputs and expected sample outputs.

Comment: Also, I would suggest splitting your code apart rather than having it all in one line. For example, one line might be `var bob = s * l / f;`. By splitting it up, you can debug through it line by line. Before each line executes ask yourself 'what value do I expect here?'. Then run the line. If you didn't get the value you expected, your bug (or one of your bugs) is on that line.

Answer (score 6):

I tested this out and got the result of -0.02. Try splitting up the code to make it more legible. It might help you diagnose the syntax of your complex equation on one line.

```
double f = 2;
double n = 2;
double s = 2;
double w = 2;
double l = 2;


double A = Math.Pow(f, n);
double B = (s * l) / f;
double C = Math.Pow((20 / f), w);
double bottom = Math.Pow(20, n);
double top = A * (B + C);
double answer = 1 - top / bottom;
```

Answer (score 2):

In both attempts you just got your brackets in the wrong spot.

Try this:

```
double answer =
    1 - Math.Pow(f, n) * (s * l / f + Math.Pow((20 / f), w)) / Math.Pow(20, n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the formula below instead:

`double answer = (1 - Math.pow((Math.pow(f,n)*[s*l/f+20/f})),w)/Math.pow(20,f)`

Comment: Your proposed formula is not correct. The variables have been used mistakenly and your solution needs to be reconsidered carefully.